# Random (not always) after cold boot asked to enter password. Fedora 24

Tags: boot, passwords, fedora

Random (not always)  after cold boot asked to enter password. Fedora 24.

This happens before login screen shows up where I again must enter user name / password.

uname -a shows:
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.7.2-201.fc24.i686 #1 SMP Fri Aug 26 16:39:49 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Could this be some malware?

Comment: encrypted partition?

Comment: @Jakuje:  No encryption on any drives.

Comment: And how does it look like?

Comment: On black screen whitish input box in middle with 'Password' above it.

Comment: Solved. It was my network drive (WDMyCloud). We replaced modem/router which defaulted to new set of IP addreses - dialog asking for password changed: "Password for: 'path to cloud drive'"